# How should I troubleshoot my Alt + Number keyboard shortcuts not working on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I recently upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11. I noticed that the Alt+0151 and Alt+0150 keyboard shortcuts don't work. **Note:** I'm assuming those keyboard shortcuts are for typing the en dash and em dash--see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-life-hacks/writing/types-of-dashes.

Can you advise about how to fix my missing keyboard shortcuts? And also, please mention any general troubleshooting methods for keyboard issues on Windows (I'm a new Windows user).

Comment: It might be easier to use Auto HotKey for shortcuts

Comment: Perhaps a BIOS setting also changed -- on some PC's, whether the *Fn* key needs to be pressed while using Alt is controlled there. Also, @John, the question is actually about typing special characters composed using the Alt key combos -- see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/alt-codes-special-characters-keyboard-symbols-windows-list/ , **not** just about shortcuts to apps.